# All tag/category/custom taxonomy archives 404

Tags: taxonomy, archives, 404-error

My issue is that `mysite.com/tag` and `mysite.com/tags` returns **404 errors**. But if I have an *eyeteeth* tag then `mysite.com/tags/eyeteeth` returns posts with that tag. This also holds true for categories, and for several custom taxonomies I've added.

`mysite.com/[taxonomy]` returns a **404 error**, but `mysite.com/[taxonomy]/[term]` returns relevant results.

I have flushed my permalink settings, and I have spent about ten hours going through every post I can find regarding taxonomy archives, trying different rewrite solutions, and so on.

Why would my taxonomy archives return 404 errors, but *taxonomy/term* results work correctly?

Comment: What would you expect to see on one of those pages? Posts with *any* term from that taxonomy? The Loop only outputs posts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think there's a default page or template that lists all tags so you'd have to create one. Did you try creating a page with a "tags" slug and assigning it a template ?

Comment: I did, yes, just got a blank page. Regardless, the wp hierarchy defaults all the way down to index.php, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @EyeTeeth You don't always get redirected to the homepage (which index.php is not) which is why you get a 404. In other terms, you might go all the way down to index.php but if nothing matches your query, you get a 404. You got a blank page when you created a "mysite.com/tags" page and that is your issue. Did you assign it a template, and is your template correct ? Did you get any errors outputted ?